# Split formatted string into list of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with person names along with their city names

```
>     John ((Rio de Janeiro); Brazil); Peter Edmund Hilary (New Delhi, (India))
```

I want to split them into

```
>     John ((Rio de Janeiro); Brazil)
>     Peter Edmund Hilary (New Delhi, (India))
```

Basically, split the author by semicolon, but ignore the semicolon if they are inside brackets.

Is there a regular expression which would do the trick?

Comment: You could Split by `;` and check if the first one `.Contains` a `)`, if not, `.Concat` with the following one.

Comment: `([^;]*?\(.*?\));` maybe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be sure that the `;` will always follow a `)`, and there will be no patterns like `);` nested inside the parentheses, then this would work:

```
Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=\));\s*")
```

---

Given your update, I'd suggest a different strategy. Regular expressions are not very well suited for parsing this kind of recursive structure (nested parentheses). However, you can use [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#balancing_group_definition) to recursively parse the parentheses, like this:

```
var input = "John ((Rio de Janeiro); Brazil); Peter Edmund Hilary (New Delhi, (India))";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([^;()\s]+\s*(\(((?<p>\()|(?<-p>\))|[^()]*)+\))?\s*)+");
var array = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g: thanks for the answer. Sorry, It is possible that a `);` could be within the paranthesis. I updated the question to reflect the same.

Comment: Many thanks! The solution works exactly as I need it to! I should now study the concepts behind. :)

Comment: @itsbalur Yes, balancing groups are very difficult to get your head around, and they are a feature of the .NET regex engine that I've never seen elsewhere. That means it's very difficult to maintain, so I probably wouldn't recommend using this code in production if you can find a simpler way around it. But I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean there is a possibility that the balancing groups feature would could be deprecated in the future?

Comment: @itsbalur No, I mean that if you or another developer needs to tweak this later, just trying to decypher that pattern would be very difficult, and without a *firm* grasp of the concepts behind it, it's easy to introduce further issues. If possible, I'd recommend trying to clean up this data at the source, so you don't have to try to parse it with such a complex regex.